# Splitting header row elements into separate rows one below the other by modifying VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

Current Output[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxNPF.png)
Expected output[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHRvs.png)
Whenever I change the code the data below the header gets overwritten. This macro returns 4 excel tabs.
the code is here:

```
Sub Import_Data()
Dim lastrow As Long

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Select
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row


'For i = 2 To lastrow
'ActiveSheet.Select
'Range("C" & i).Value = Range("C" & i).Value / 1000000
'Next i



ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B" & lastrow).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Industry Comparables (1 of 3)").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A8").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("Industry Comparables (2 of 3)").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("Industry Comparables (3 of 3)").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Select
ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveSheet.Range("C1:O" & lastrow).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Industry Comparables (1 of 3)").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("C8").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Range("B8").Value = "Name"
Range("C8").Value = "Market Cap ($ Mil.) (Most Recent Month End)"
Range("D8").Value = "Assets to Equity (CY)"
Range("E8").Value = "Assets to Equity (PY)"
Range("F8").Value = "Asset Turn- over (CY)"
Range("G8").Value = "Asset Turn- over (PY)"
Range("H8").Value = "Sales /Inven Turn- over (CY)"
Range("I8").Value = "Sales /Inven Turn- over (PY)"
Range("J8").Value = "Receiv- ables Turn- over (CY)"
Range("K8").Value = "Receiv- ables Turn- over (PY)"
Range("L8").Value = "Current Ratio (CY)"
Range("M8").Value = "Current Ratio (PY)"
Range("N8").Value = "Quick Ratio (CY)"
Range("O8").Value = "Quick Ratio (PY)"
Range("B10:B12").Select
Selection.ClearContents

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Select
ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveSheet.Range("P1:Y" & lastrow).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Industry Comparables (2 of 3)").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("C7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B7").Value = "Name"
Range("C7").Value = "Total Debt% Total Assets (CY)"
Range("D7").Value = "Total Debt% Total Assets (PY)"
Range("E7").Value = "Total Debt% Total Equity (CY)"
Range("F7").Value = "Total Debt% Total Equity (PY)"
Range("G7").Value = "L T Debt% Total Capital (CY)"
Range("H7").Value = "L T Debt% Total Capital (PY)"
Range("I7").Value = "S T Debt% Total Debt (CY)"
Range("J7").Value = "S T Debt% Total Debt (PY)"
Range("K7").Value = "Net Cash Fl % Total Debt (CY)"
Range("L7").Value = "Net Cash Fl % Total Debt (PY)"

Range("B9:B11").Select
Selection.ClearContents

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Select
ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveSheet.Range("Z1:AK" & lastrow).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Industry Comparables (3 of 3)").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("C7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Range("B7").Value = "Name"
Range("C7").Value = "Gross Income Margin (CY)"
Range("D7").Value = "Gross Income Margin (PY)"
Range("E7").Value = "Net Income Margin (CY)"
Range("F7").Value = "Net Income Margin (PY)"
Range("G7").Value = "Oper Margin (CY)"
Range("H7").Value = "Oper Margin (PY)"
Range("I7").Value = "Return on Avg Total Equity (CY)"
Range("J7").Value = "Return on Avg Total Equity (PY)"
Range("K7").Value = "Basic EPS Before Extra- ordinary Items (CY)"
Range("L7").Value = "Basic EPS Before Extra- ordinary Items (PY)"
Range("M7").Value = "Diluted EPS Before Extra- Ordinary Items (CY)"
Range("N7").Value = "Diluted EPS Before Extra- Ordinary Items (PY)"

Range("B9:B11").Select
Selection.ClearContents


Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Sheets(4).Delete
'Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub

Sub Comp1Macro()

    Dim lastrow As Integer

Sheets("Industry Comparables (1 of 3)").Select
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 0
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "GICS Industry-" & Sheets(4).Range("AN2").Value
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 12
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "The following is an analysis of key ratios/metrics for the issuer compared to other issuers in the same industry."
    'Rows("3:7").Select
    'Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "Current Year (CY) ratios are based on each issuer's most recent fiscal year end financials."
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "Prior Year (PY) ratios are based on the year prior to each issuer's most recent fiscal year end financials."
    Range("A6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Note 1 - Market Cap is as of most recent month end prior to this issuer profile report date."
    Range("A2:A4").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    'Rows("8:17").Select
    'Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A8:O8").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    With Selection.Interior
        .ColorIndex = 9
        .Pattern = xlSolid
    End With
    Rows("8:8").EntireRow.AutoFit
    Range("A8:O8").Select
    Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    Range("A8").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    'Rows("9:12").Select
    'Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("A9:O9").Select
    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Range("A9:B9").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Range("C9:O9").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Range("A10").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range("A10:O12").Select
    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
    Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 2
    Range("A10").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Upper quartile of Comparables"
    Range("A11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Median of Comparables"
    Range("A12").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Lower quartile of Comparables"
    Range("A10:O12").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A13").End(xlDown).Row
    Range("A13").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Range("A13:O" & lastrow).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    Range("B8").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Range("C8").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Range("C8:C" & lastrow).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    Range("D8").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Range("D8:E" & lastrow).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("F8").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Range("F8:G" & lastrow).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("H8").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Range("H8:I" & lastrow).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("J8").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Range("J8:K" & lastrow).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("L8").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Range("L8:M" & lastrow).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("N8").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Range("N8:O" & lastrow).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("A8").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Range("A8:O" & lastrow).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 8
    Range("B:B").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 21
    Range("A9:B9").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
'    Selection.Merge
    Range("A10:B10").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    Range("A11:B11").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    Range("A12:B12").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Range("A9:O12").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlMedium
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Range("A1:O" & lastrow).Select
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$O$" & lastrow
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$12"
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$O$" & lastrow
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = "&"",Bold""&11Confidential - Not for External Distribution"
        .LeftFooter = "&P of &N"
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = "&"",Bold""&11Comparable 1 of 3&"",Regular""&9" & Chr(10) & ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 70
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    End With
    Selection.Replace What:="#N/A", Replacement:="No Data", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    Columns("P:P").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("C9:O" & lastrow).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0.0_);_(* (#,##0.0);_(* ""-""?_);_(@_)"
    Range("A9:O9").Select
    With Selection
        Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 1
    End With
 Cells.Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With

        Range("A8:O" & lastrow).Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 10
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With


End Sub
```

There is a similar code for the next 4 tabs which are generated as output after running this macro. I want the same result for all the tabs. If the answer i get for this code works then I can similarly tweak the other codes.
thank you

Comment: Would help your question a lot to remove all the irrelevant parts of the code.

Comment: Your two "outputs" also seem to be the same...

Comment: Hi, tim I have update the current and expected output image

Comment: Way to much code to be certain and not sure I understand your question, but it might be of your lines that look like lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A13").End(xlDown).Row. Looks like the two header rows are in colums D and onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required change is pretty straightforward but to be honest the code is in need of a total re-write, and there's so much of it that it's unlikely anyone is going to do that for you.

```
Range("B7").Value = "Name"
Range("C7").Value = "Gross Income Margin"
Range("D7").Value = "Gross Income Margin"
Range("E7").Value = "Net Income Margin"
Range("F7").Value = "Net Income Margin"
'etc

Range("B8").Value = ""
Range("C8").Value = "(CY)"
Range("D8").Value = "(PY)"
Range("E8").Value = "(CY)"
Range("F8").Value = "(PY)"
'etc
```

Comment: Thank you Tim,This worked for me, However the data was overwritten. The code which copy and pastes the data is here Sheets              ("Industry Comparables (1 of 3)").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A8").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste                                                                                  Is there a way I can add a blank row in between so that after the headers which are on cell A8, there is a blank row on A9 and all the data is pasted from cell A10 - Looking forward to your response. Thank you

Comment: Thank you @tim williams,This worked for me, However the data was overwritten. The code which copy and pastes the data is here Sheets              ("Industry Comparables (1 of 3)").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A8").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste                                                                                  Is there a way I can add a blank row in between so that after the headers which are on cell A8-O8, there is a blank row on A9-O9 and all the data is pasted from cell A10 - Looking forward to your response. Thank you

Comment: Just paste one row lower `ActiveSheet.Range("A9").Select : ActiveSheet.Paste`

Comment: the data which I am copying already has headers, if I paste on cell "A9" it will shift everything below by one including the headers which I don't want. All I want is a blank row being inserted between the header and the actual data while pasting it.